# How to insert an LLVM StoreInst in a Basic Block

Tags: c++, llvm

I am going through instructions in a basic block. After an allocation instruction I want to make a store for that variable and insert it right after the allocation instruction.
Right now I am able to find the Allocation instruction with

```
if(AllocaInst *AI=dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(&i))
```

but i do not know how to create the StoreInst. I just want to store the number 10 in it regardless of which type the variable is.

I tried like this

```
StoreInst* stinst = new StoreInst(Value *Val, Value *Ptr, Instruction *InsertBefore);
```

but i do not know what to put in place of Val, Ptr, and how to get the adress of the next instruction if it needs a pointer to InsertBefore

Comment: Using LLVM without a solid understanding of C++ is madness. You should come up to speed with the language first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert something **after** instruction you can use [insertAfter() method](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#af09e4096de244d2fb345891328714a63). In your case:

```
AI->insertAfter(stinst)
```

And to create `StoreInst` you need to provide it with

- `Value *Val` is what you want to store. In your case you'd need to create a `Constant` that would represent "10" integer and then pass it there.
- `Value *Ptr` is where you want to put the value. I guess, it is `AI` in your case.
- `nullptr` for `Instruction *InsertBefore`, because you are inserting it manually.

Comment: `insertAfter` will insert `AI` after `stinst`.